# Turn list to a graph

Tags: r

I have a function that lists all the accessible environments in the current session.

Edited output:

```
[[1]]
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

[[2]]
<environment: package:igraph>
attr(,"name")
[1] "package:igraph"
attr(,"path")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/igraph"

[[3]]
<environment: package:stats>
attr(,"name")
[1] "package:stats"
attr(,"path")
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1-arm64/Resources/library/stats"

[[4]]
<environment: R_EmptyEnv>

[[5]]
<environment: namespace:igraph>

[[6]]
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Could you advise approach to convert this list to a graph? I want to plot it with igraph later.
Elements 1, 2, 3 probably should be nodes, but then what is the best way to denote edges, connecting parent and child environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way to do this is to create an edgelist as a two-column character matrix with each environment's name in the left column, and its parent's name in the right column:

```r
library(igraph)

my_envs <- env_list(globalenv())

edgelist <- t(sapply(my_envs[-length(my_envs)], function(x) {
   c(environmentName(x), environmentName(parent.env(x)))
}))

g <- graph_from_edgelist(edgelist)

plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: you've helped me so much lately! maybe you know how to add namespaces to this environment listing function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that @Aella. Can you give an example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the function `env_names` lists accessible environments in the current session. Above I have edited how its desired output should look like. I wonder what can be done so that it would list environment namespaces too, then the graph plot would look much more interesting :)

Comment: @Aella I don't really understand this. The original function returns all attached environments on the path, which already include the igraph and stats packages. Adding their namespaces as environments as parents of the empty environment doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you could explain a bit what this is meant to show?

Comment: I thought that if namespaces would be added to this list, graph will be larger and have branches

Comment: @Aella no, I'm afraid not - this isn't how the search path is structured in R. It is possible to have nested environments in R, but that's not how the search path is.